# Cleaning and standardizing object text into categories (python, pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have to standardize several object columns into categories before hot coding the few remaining categories for use in a clustering algorithm.

Here is an example:

1. There is a dataset with five attributes with about nine hundred records (`df`)
2. One of these attributes is for beverages (`df.beverages`).
3. `df.beverages` has 74 factor levels, but really we want to bin these into four groups:

   -milk

   -water

   -soda

   -other
4. Values appear like 'chocolate milk', 'iced water', 'Pepsi soda', 'wine'.
5. I would like the values to convert to 'milk', 'water', 'soda', 'other'.

How can I use wildcards (*/%/other) and/or an else/if statement to do this efficiently?  Can this just overwrite the original values?

Comment: Just create a dictionary for all the "outliers" with a key of the existing value and value of the desired category string.  Then just replace all the values with dictionary equivalents.  I don't know the exact syntax.  You could even be clever and create a parse program for unknowns (like using re matching).

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function that receiving a string and returning the category:

```py
def categorize_beverages(x):
    if 'soda' in x:
        return 'soda'
    elif 'water' in x:
        return 'water'
    elif 'milk' in x:
        return 'milk'
    else:
        return 'other'
```

This is just a "quick and dirty" function that checks if some string (soda/water/milk) is inside a string, but you can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) as much as you like. Essentially this is just a custom function that given a string, returns the category.

Then we want for each value to add the relevant category: for this `.map` is useful [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). It returns a series, applying for each column separately your custom function.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'beverages': ['wine', 'chocolate milk', 'iced water', 'Pepsi soda']})
df['beverages_category'] = df['beverages'].map(categorize_beverages)
```

Output:

```py
df
Out[34]: 
        beverages beverages_category
0            wine              other
1  chocolate milk               milk
2      iced water              water
3      Pepsi soda               soda
```

of course, you can override the entries by writing `df['beverages'] =`  instead of `df['beverages_category'] =`

Note: `.map` can be a bit slow if you have large dataframes (millions of rows), but with 900 rows it should be fine (depends on the performance of your custom function of course)